# count all values that's greater than 0.8 within the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

This is the data:

```
tmp <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), perc = c(1, 0.996059244, 
1.001618656, 0.997829726, 0.915108419, 0.92539353, 0.047364961, 
0.017640387, 0.036429124, 0.045454043, -0.006316982, 0.025515999, 
-0.011243315, 0.00177058, 0.083566957, 0.018730071, 10.893466942, 
0.635321677, 0.486662427, 0.421685776, 0.398957515, 0.397167489, 
0.406132297, 0.42004932, 0.436092126, 0.451437885, 0.469267847, 
0.484069249, 0.496775105, 0.510017824, 0.517280558, 1, 0.970310965, 
0.920600257, 0.801496781, 0.635352677, 0.351879201, 0.133918706, 
0.020005058, -0.003554937, -0.027281619, -0.030216871, -0.035568669, 
-0.018927467, -0.054635806, -0.023042942, -0.049607356, 1), breakpoint = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -48L), groups = structure(list(id = c(1, 
2, 3), .rows = structure(list(1:16, 17:32, 33:48), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I want to count the values greater than 0.8 and record it to a new column, group by ID, so far I'm able to use ifelse to get 0 and 1 and store in another column, but get stuck after that...
What I tried:

```
tmp <- tmp %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(breakpoint = ifelse(perc >= 0.8, 1,0))
```

This is my desired out:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), percentage = c(1, 0.996059244, 1.001618656, 
0.997829726, 0.915108419, 0.92539353, 0.047364961, 0.017640387, 
0.036429124, 0.045454043, -0.006316982, 0.025515999, -0.011243315, 
0.00177058, 0.083566957, 0.018730071, 1, 0.893466942, 0.635321677, 
0.486662427, 0.421685776, 0.398957515, 0.397167489, 0.406132297, 
0.42004932, 0.436092126, 0.451437885, 0.469267847, 0.484069249, 
0.496775105, 0.510017824, 0.517280558, 1, 0.970310965, 0.920600257, 
0.801496781, 0.635352677, 0.351879201, 0.133918706, 0.020005058, 
-0.003554937, -0.027281619, -0.030216871, -0.035568669, -0.018927467, 
-0.054635806, -0.023042942, -0.049607356), breakpoint = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

[image: desired output]

Can someone also tell me how to display the output as code? Only know to use ctrl+k...Thanks!

Comment: Your `tmp` contains only 3 id, while your `output` contains 16.

Comment: Are you looking for `dplyr::summarize`? Try  `tmp %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(breakpoint = sum(breakpoint))`?

Comment: I updated my output

Comment: I don't get your desired output. Why is in breakpoint all the time NA and when there should be a number? And what does this has to do with 0.8?

Comment: Hello, summary is not what I need exactly, so it has to be: find the first row that's smaller than 0.8 and only count the > 0.8 values above this value

Comment: @Solicia You will have to update your data with your new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty not sure about your purpose, and please note that in `id 2`, `perc` is `10.9` then `.635` which is smaller than `0.8`, so maybe count you want is `1`.(?)

Please check this out with `dput` object(`tmp`) you provided.

```
tmp %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(key = (cumsum(perc < 0.8) == 0) * (perc > 0.8)) %>%
  summarize(key = sum(key))

     id   key
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     6
2     2     1
3     3     3
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, this is not my real data, I made up the data so it might not be a perfect example. so let's say I have perc: 0.9, 0.98, 0.95, 0.7, 0.88, if I do summary it will be 4, but I only want the >0.8 values before <0.8 so it's 3. Hope this make sense.

Comment: @Solicia Try my code to your data. I think I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(res = cumsum(breakpoint)*breakpoint,
         res = res * NA ^(res != max(res)))

  id         perc breakpoint res
1   1  1.000000000          1  NA
2   1  0.996059244          1  NA
3   1  1.001618656          1  NA
4   1  0.997829726          1  NA
5   1  0.915108419          1  NA
6   1  0.925393530          1   6
7   1  0.047364961          0  NA
8   1  0.017640387          0  NA
9   1  0.036429124          0  NA
10  1  0.045454043          0  NA
11  1 -0.006316982          0  NA
12  1  0.025515999          0  NA
13  1 -0.011243315          0  NA
14  1  0.001770580          0  NA
15  1  0.083566957          0  NA
16  1  0.018730071          0  NA
17  2 10.893466942          1  NA
18  2  0.635321677          0  NA
19  2  0.486662427          0  NA
20  2  0.421685776          0  NA
21  2  0.398957515          0  NA
22  2  0.397167489          0  NA
23  2  0.406132297          0  NA
24  2  0.420049320          0  NA
25  2  0.436092126          0  NA
26  2  0.451437885          0  NA
27  2  0.469267847          0  NA
28  2  0.484069249          0  NA
29  2  0.496775105          0  NA
30  2  0.510017824          0  NA
31  2  0.517280558          0  NA
32  2  1.000000000          1   2
33  3  0.970310965          1  NA
34  3  0.920600257          1  NA
35  3  0.801496781          1  NA
36  3  0.635352677          0  NA
37  3  0.351879201          0  NA
38  3  0.133918706          0  NA
39  3  0.020005058          0  NA
40  3 -0.003554937          0  NA
41  3 -0.027281619          0  NA
42  3 -0.030216871          0  NA
43  3 -0.035568669          0  NA
44  3 -0.018927467          0  NA
45  3 -0.054635806          0  NA
46  3 -0.023042942          0  NA
47  3 -0.049607356          0  NA
48  3  1.000000000          1   4
>
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I don't mean to have the NAs there... What I need is to find the first row that's smaller than 0.8 and only count the > 0.8 values above this value

Comment: @Solicia so what exactly do you want? This gives exactly the same results as the output you provided

Comment: @Solicia changing the Output makes this code not worthwhile. Anyway the other answer given provides the results you want.

Comment: I updated the output, so for example I have perc: 0.9, 0.98, 0.95, 0.7, 0.88, if I do summary it will be 4, but I only want the >0.8 values before <0.8 so it's 3. Hope this make sense...

Comment: @Solicia Let me update my solution asap

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id)%>%
    dplyr::summarise(new = sum(perc >= 0.8))
```

```
     id   new
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     6
2     2     2
3     3     4
```

Comment: The output has three ID's take a look at it

Comment: Ah OK. He must have edited it.

Comment: Hello, summary is not what I need exactly, so it has to be: find the first row that's smaller than 0.8 and only count the > 0.8 values above this value